# USB devices take quite some time to recognize every time

Tags: usb

I don't know exactly when this thing started, but basically every usb device I plug in (usb controller, usb flash drive etc), the process System starts writing 100% on the HDD (in the meantime the device is not detected), when it finishes the device is ready. This happens everytime, even if I plug it in the same port. I don't know how to solve this, any idea? I tried uninstalling the "controller" drivers under the usb list on the hardware management page but no luck

Comment: Have you checked the Event Viewer for System or Application messages around the time you connect new devices? Have you updated drivers on your computer? Have you found a USB device you have not connected before and tried it? Have you tried the problematic USB devices on a different computer?